# Inserting line along line using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, line

I try to insert a line between two lines. End points of lines are in intersection of lines. I use positionAlongLine in arcpy but it interestingly gets coordinates from the first points of referenced lines even if I use `shape.positionAlongLine(0.05).lastPoint` Also I get 5cm distance but it generated very long lines. The lines created like the picture. Red lines are generated, blue lines are referenced. The result is oposite of what I want. How to acquire a line using positionAlongLine?
[image]

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Asus\Documents\workspace\PROJECTS\output\output_data.gdb"
coords = []
point = arcpy.Point()
array = arcpy.Array()
featureList = []
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(r"anahtar_line")
feat = cursor.newRow()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("line", ["OBJECTID", "SHAPE@"]) as scursor:
    for row in scursor:
        shape = row[1]
        end = shape.lastPoint
        point.X = end.X
        point.Y = end.Y
        array.add(point)
        d = shape.positionAlongLine(0.05).lastPoint
        point.X = d.X
        point.Y = d.Y
        array.add(point)
        polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
        array.removeAll()
        featureList.append(polyline)
        feat.shape = polyline
        cursor.insertRow(feat)
del feat
del cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by flipping lines. I appended last and first coordinates into a list. In order to generate one line, I limited it with len(coords).

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Asus\Documents\workspace\PROJECTS\SCADA\others\scripts\output\output_data.gdb"
print arcpy.env.workspace
coords = []
point = arcpy.Point()
array = arcpy.Array()
featureList = []
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(r"anahtar_line")
feat = cursor.newRow()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("line_Selected", ["OBJECTID", "SHAPE@"]) as scursor:
    for row in scursor:
        shape = row[1]
        first = shape.firstPoint
        end = shape.lastPoint
        coords.append([(first.X, first.Y), (end.X, end.Y)])
        if len(coords)>1:
            pass
        else:
            point.X = first.X
            point.Y = first.Y
            array.add(point)
            d = shape.positionAlongLine(0.05).lastPoint
            point.X = d.X
            point.Y = d.Y
            array.add(point)
            polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
            array.removeAll()
            featureList.append(polyline)
            feat.shape = polyline
            cursor.insertRow(feat)
    print coords[1][1]
    print coords[0][1]
    print len(coords)
    if coords[1][1] == coords[0][1]:
        arcpy.FlipLine_edit("line_Selected")
del feat
del cursor
```